# how to ignore the bad message in kafka jdbc sink connector?

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

I'm using kafka JDBC connector to push data from kafka topic to postgres on aws. However, when a bad message occurs, for example, the data type in the message is different from what is defined in the database, I get error message:

ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=postgres_sink -0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:584)

Then I have to delete my jdbc sink connector (pod) manually and let it start a new one. Since I am running in a standalone mode, I need to prevent the connector (pod) from failing or restart automatically because an insert failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can apply deadletter queue and set `error.tolerances = all` to push the bad message to another topic then we can review later.

The more detail in this [link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/)